# Does rewind and fsetpos can also intervene the C file append mode subsequent writes?

Tags: c, file, append, standards, mode

[C11 Working Draft Standard N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) said that on page 306 at "7.21.5.3 The fopen function" section

> Opening a file with append mode (**'a'** as the first character in the **mode** argument) causes all subsequent writes to the file to be forced to the then current end-of-file, regardless of intervening calls to the **fseek** function. ...

Can anybody confirms that not only **fseek** function but also other file positioning function such as **fsetpos** and **rewind** can't intervene the append mode?

Well, the standard on page 338 said that rewind does a similar thing with **(void)fseek(stream, 0L, SEEK_SET)** except that the error indicator for the stream is also cleared. But as far as I have read on page 337 the standard does not state that fsetpos similar to fseek.

---

Source Code to illustrate this problem

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Declare the File Pointer
    FILE *fp;

// Declare the test integer variable
    int TEST;

// declare the test position variable for fsetpos test
    fpos_t POSITION;

void WriteData(int choice){
    // Clear the file content
        fp = fopen("test.bin", "wb"); fclose(fp);

    // Reopen the file with ab
        fp = fopen("test.bin", "ab");

    // Initialize the test integer variable
        TEST = 100;

    // Write five sample data
        int i;
        for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

            fwrite(&TEST, sizeof(TEST), 1, fp);

            // If two data were written then save the position
            if( i == 2 ) 
                fgetpos(fp, &POSITION);
        }

    //  Change the data
        TEST = 54321;   

    // Declare the test case
        switch(choice){
            case 1 : fseek(fp, (long) 2*sizeof(TEST), SEEK_SET); break;
            case 2 : rewind(fp); break;
            case 3 : fsetpos(fp, &POSITION); break;
        }

    // Write the data again
        fwrite(&TEST, sizeof(TEST), 1, fp);

    // Close the file
        fclose(fp);
}


void ReadData(){
    // Open the file for read
        fp = fopen("test.bin", "rb");

        printf("\n [OUTPUT]");
    // while the data can be read then print it to the console
        while( fread(&TEST, sizeof(TEST), 1, fp) == 1)
            printf("\n %d", TEST);

    // Close the file
        fclose(fp);
}

int main(){

    /* Test Case Process */
        printf("\n\n Intervene using fseek(fp, (long) 2*sizeof(TEST), SEEK_SET);");
        WriteData(1);
        ReadData();

        printf("\n\n Intervene using rewind(fp);");
        WriteData(2);
        ReadData();

        printf("\n\n Intervene using fsetpos(fp, &POSITION);");
        WriteData(3);
        ReadData();




    return 0;
}
```

---

The desired output:

```
 Intervene using fseek(fp, (long) 2*sizeof(TEST), SEEK_SET);
 [OUTPUT]
 100
 100
 100
 100
 100
 54321

 Intervene using rewind(fp);
 [OUTPUT]
 100
 100
 100
 100
 100
 54321

 Intervene using fsetpos(fp, &POSITION);
 [OUTPUT]
 100
 100
 100
 100
 100
 54321
```

If the output were like that, then the standard does confirms that not only **fseek** function that can't intervene the subsequent writes, but also **rewind** and **fsetpos**. Else if the output were not like that, then the standard does not confirms it.

### I have test it on windows 10 using tdm-gcc 4.9.2 and on Ubuntu 16.04 gcc 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4). The result is that three of them can't intervene, but I'm not sure in other platform whether it can't intervene or not.

Finally, If I might re-ask my question again. Does the standard also confirms that not only **fseek** function that can't intervene the seubsequent writes, but also **rewind** and **fsetpos**?

If the standard **confirms** then please explain where does the statement which indicate the confirmation.

Else if the standard **does not confirms** then please explain where does the statement which indicate the denial.

About my question, what I need to know is the **certainty** that standard does confirms the compiler writer must exactly do this or do that etc. in order to confirms the standard, nothing more

Comment: This seems like something you shouldn't need to know - you can't use fsetpos and rewind anyway (because they don't work on Windows) and if you want to be able to seek then why not not use append mode?

Comment: @immibis are you sure? What compiler that you use? fseek fsetpos and rewind are declared in stdio.h, of course I definitely can use it. I need to confirms in order to make people not misunderstood. Of course is it useful because  you can seek the file with update mode 'ab+' for reading

Comment: @immibis, it depends on the libc implementation, not windows per se. If tdm-gcc uses a "posix-like" libc, these calls might work.

Comment: @immibis: The `rewind()` and `fsetpos()` functions are part of standard C.  C90 included `rewind()`; `fsetpos()` and `fgetpos()` were added to C99.  Therefore, `rewind()` should certainly work on Windows, and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51hy3tts.aspx) indicates `fsetpos()` should work in VS 2015 and versions back to VS .NET 2003.

Comment: @Unknown123 I mean you can't use them to do what you want, because they don't do what you want on Windows.

Comment: Prof. Falken Jonathan Leffler @immibis
Pardon me, but the [http://read.pudn.com/downloads133/doc/565041/ANSI_ISO%2B9899-1990%2B[1].pdf](**C90 Standard**) explain that : **rewind** function does exist on page 146 at 7.9.9.5 section, **fsetpos** function on page 146 at 7.9.9.3 section, **fgetpos** function on page 145 at 7.9.9.1 section, and fseek function on page 145 at 7.9.9.2 section.
How can even a nowadays compilers are not conforming just a small parts of C90 standard?

Please check my updated question above to better illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

With stream I/O, neither [`rewind()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rewind.html) nor [`fsetpos()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fsetpos.html) overrides the append mode — any more than [`fseek()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fseek.html) does.  The implicit seek for append mode happens when the write occurs; the positioning operation is separate and only affects where the implicit seek starts from, not where the write occurs.

With file descriptor I/O, [`pwrite()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pwrite.html) — positioned write — does override append mode but other operations do not.  POSIX states: *The `pwrite()` function shall be equivalent to `write()`, except that it writes into a given position and does not change the file offset (regardless of whether `O_APPEND` is set).*

Comment: I have update my question to better illustrate the problem and please explain which part of the standard which confirms that not only fseek function that can intervene the seubsequent writes, but also rewind and fsetpos.

Comment: Beware on Linux.  [`pwrite()` on Linux is broken](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html):  "POSIX requires that opening a file with the `O_APPEND` flag should have
       no effect on the location at which `pwrite()` writes data.  However, on
       Linux, if a file is opened with `O_APPEND`, `pwrite()` appends data to
       the end of the file, regardless of the value of *offset*."

Comment: @Unknown123: Nothing has changed. The append mode on a file stream operates strictly at the level of each write operation.  Whenever a write occurs, it occurs at the end of the file — regardless of what else has happened with the seek position in the interim, and regardless of which mechanism ([`fseeko()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fseeko.html) anybody?) is used to do the positioning.  When the write occurs, it occurs at the end of the file.  Full stop.  Period.  No negotiations.  No caveats.  No whingeing.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: That's a curious bug — mildly worrying.  Not that you often use `pwrite()` with a file opened for `O_APPEND`.  Thanks for the information.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No, it's not often useful, but a POSIX-compliant implementation allows a multithreaded process to open a file with `O_APPEND` set and, without any locking, either extend with `write()` or write to any location with `pwrite()`.  Works great, as long as you don't care about "last `pwrite()` to a location wins".  Linux doesn't support that.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I'm sorry if I irritate you and make you think that I'm whinging while actually I'm not. Thank you, but you are still don't give me the certainty. If I look carefully to the standard,  the C standard isn't as clear as it could be, it contains ambiguity. It depends on the one who is interpret it.

Comment: I don't know how the standard could make it clearer.  It says that writes on a file opened in append mode are made at the end of the file — period.  The 'regardless' does only mention `fseek()`, but that's incidental.  The behaviour is specified: _all subsequent writes to the file [are] forced to the then current end-of-file_ — what could be clearer?  If you want greater clarity, you're may have write a Defect Report to the Standard C committee asking them to explain why `fsetpos()` and `rewind()` aren't mentioned when `fseek()` is.  Or you'll have to find someone else who can answer, somehow.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler How to send a defect report? Where should I send it? To be honest, I can't find any useful information in google, would you like to help me?

Comment: I don't know how you'd submit a defect report.  I think it has to go through your country standards body.  You can try to find out more at the C standard committee's web site, [http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/), perhaps, or you can find out more from [ISO](http://www.iso.org/).  However, I don't think it is worth trying to submit a DR on this.  I do not wish to be involved; I have stated clearly that I don't think the standard is really ambiguous.